# Parametric Mimima of Two Moving Points

Tags: calculus

At noon, one ship (A) was 100km directly north of another ship (B). Ship A was sailing south at 30 kph and B was sailing east at 15kph. After how many hours will the two ships be nearest each other?

The Answer is 2.67

If we turn the pythagorean theorem into a parametric equation we get;

```
2D(dD/dt)^2 = (2x(dx/dT))^2 +(2y(dy/dT))^2
```

Initial Distances are the following

```
D = 100
x = 0
y = 100
```

We also get the following rates:

```
dx/dT = 15kpH
dy/dT = -30kpH
```

If we substitute all of it into the equation we get; -15kPh for dD/dT then I realize. I have to set dD/dT = 0 in order to get minima; just like when i set y' to 0 in other problems. I know im missing another equation? method? Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ships, suppose that Ship B is at the origin.

Then the equation for the position is Ship  is $p_B(t) = (15t,0)$, where $t$ is
the elapsed time in hours. The equation for the position of Ship A is
$p_A(t) = (0, 100-30t)$.

Then the distance squared between them is described by $s(t) = \|p_A(t)-p_B(t)\|^2$.

Compute this formula, differentiate with respect to $t$ and determine the
time at which the minimum occurs. Use this to find the closest distance.

**Notes**: (1) You can pick any initial point, not just the origin, as the distance between the boats will remain the same. (2) We use the distance squared because it is a simpler formula the the distance (no square root) and, not that it matters in this problem, it is differentiable everywhere, the distance is not differentiable at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is after $\frac{8}{3}$ hours. This is because the square of the distance in terms of t is, as in the first answer, $f(t) =(15t)^2+(100-39t)^2=225t^2-6000t+10000$. The minimum is attained if the derivative is zero. $t=\frac{8}{3}$

Comment: I think you mean (100 * -30)^2

Comment: cant seem to get why ignore the squareroot!

Answer (score 0):

As a general result, if you express the relative displacement as a vector $\underline R$ and the relative velocity as a vector $\underline V$, then the objects are closest when the dot product $\underline R.\underline V=0$